# My React app code keeps giving an error "Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined" and I don't understand why

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [fullName, setFullname] = useState({
    fname: " ",
    lname: " "
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setFullname(prevValue => {
      if (name === "fname") {
        return {
          fname: value,
          lname: prevValue.lname
        };
      } else if (name === "lname") {
        return {
          fname: prevValue.fname,
          lname: value
        };
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Hello {fullName.fname} {fullName.lname}
      </h1>
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fName"
          value={fullName.fname}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="lName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          value={fullName.lname}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am a beginner in React, just started using hooks.
Above code renders a form which is supposed to take the first name and the last name as an input, individually, and update it in the heading in real-time. But the moment I type something it throws and error: "`×
←→1 of 7 errors on the page
TypeError
Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined`"

The Error is highlighted in the  tag variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure name attr is the same as property inside the object.

Also your `setFullname` can be simplified

```js
const [{fName, lLame}, setFullname] = useState({
    fName: " ",
    lLame: " "
  });

function handleChange({target: {name, value}}) {
    setFullname(state => ({...state, [name]: value}));
}
```

```
 <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fName"
          value={fFame}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="lName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          value={lName}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition in `handleChange` is failing. It should be

```
...
 setFullname(prevValue => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
         ....
  } else if (name === "lName") {
    return {
   ....
```

Comment: I am sorry, but isn't it the same condition that I wrote?

Comment: As @Józef pointed out - "Make sure name attr is the same as property inside the object." So, `fname` should be `fName` and `lname` should be `lName`.